# Не работает код

Tags: php

В общем, идея такова, при заходе на url, если в нем присутствует слово selection и переменная GET type, то это слово надо заменить на selectfilter и перейти по этому url, первая часть выполняется, но потом на Url, где нет selection, а есть selectfilter, идет циклическая переадресация? В чем дело? Два часа бьюсь, не пойму, пробовал и  pregmatch - то же самое. ( Помогите, люди добрые.

```
 $pos  = strripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'selection');
    if(isset($_GET['type']) and $pos === true){
    $source = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $sour = str_replace('selection', 'selectfilter', $source);
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$sour.'" />';
```

Comment: @zoinx2012, $pos === true не выполнится вообще никогда. Вы точно тот код приложили?

Comment: привет, ну, читал по мануалам, выложил свой код, а что не так, скажи, пожалуйста

Comment: @zoinx2012, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_GET['selection']))
{
  $source = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $sour = str_replace($_GET['selection'], 'selectfilter', $source);
}
```